# Gson Parsing: Bean Structure in different projects

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

Say I have 4 projects

**project-a,
project-b,
project-c,
project-common**

`project-common` is set as dependency(maven) in all the other projects.

Now each project reads separate json files.

project-a, project-b reads following json

```
 { "jsonLevel1" : { 
       "jsonLevel2" : {
            "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2"
    }
}
```

project-c reads the following:

```
  { "jsonLevel1" : { 
           "jsonLevel2" : {
                "key1" : "value1",
                "key2" :"value2",
                "key3" : "value3",
                "jsonLevel3" : {
                     "string1" : "value11",
                     "string2" : "value22"
             }
        }
    }
```

I want to have pojo classes JsonLevel1, JsonLevel2 in project-common and JavaLevel3 in project-c. But, project-common does not recognize JavaLevel3 class (as project-c is not a dependency to project-common)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have in your **project-common** the class:

JsonLevel1.java

```
public class JsonLevel1 {
    JsonLevel2 jsonLevel2;

}
```

JsonLevel2.java

```
public class JsonLevel2 {
    String key1;
    String key2;
    String key3;
    JsonLevel3 jsonLevel3;
}
```

And in JsonLevel2 class, because there isn't the JsonLevel3 class in this project, there is your problem.

You could do this. In the class JsonLevel2 you can insert, instead of the JsonLevel3 class, a Map:

```
public class JsonLevel2 {
    String key1;
    String key2;
    String key3;
    Map<String,String>jsonLevel3;

    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }

    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }

    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }

    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    public String getKey3() {
        return key3;
    }

    public void setKey3(String key3) {
        this.key3 = key3;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getJsonLevel3() {
        return jsonLevel3;
    }

    public void setJsonLevel3(Map<String, String> jsonLevel3) {
        jsonLevel3 = jsonLevel3;
    }
}
```

In this way there isn't the problem in your project-common and you are able to parse the json.

In the **project-c**, where exists the class JsonLevel3, after deserializing your json in the JsonLevel object, you can get this map and deserialize it in your JsonLevel3.

So, if you want to read this json in your  project-c:

```
{ "jsonLevel1" : { 
           "jsonLevel2" : {
                "key1" : "value1",
                "key2" :"value2",
                "key3" : "value3",
                "jsonLevel3" : {
                     "string1" : "value11",
                     "string2" : "value22"
             }
        }
    }}
```

You can do:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String filename="/pathTo/json.json";
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
        JsonLevel jsonlevel= gson.fromJson(reader, JsonLevel.class);
        System.out.println("jsonlevel: " + gson.toJson(jsonlevel));

        Map<String, String> jl3 = jsonlevel.getJsonLevel1().getJsonLevel2().getJsonLevel3();
        /*for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : jl3.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }*/
        JsonLevel3 jlev3=gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(jl3), JsonLevel3.class);
        System.out.println("jlev3: " + gson.toJson(jlev3));
```

With, of course, JsonLevel class equal to

```
public class JsonLevel {

    JsonLevel1 jsonLevel1;

    public JsonLevel1 getJsonLevel1() {
        return jsonLevel1;
    }

    public void setJsonLevel1(JsonLevel1 jsonLevel1) {
        this.jsonLevel1 = jsonLevel1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I thought your final json had the structure of the description of your question. That's why I used a `Map<String,String>` for the JsonLevel3.

If JsonLevel3 is not your last level, instead of to use a `Map<String,String>`, you can use a **`Map<String, Object>`**.

For example, if the json to is:

```
{
  "jsonLevel1":{
    "jsonLevel2":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3",
      "jsonLevel3":{
        "string1":"value11",
        "string2":"value22",
        "jsonLevel4":{
          "int1":1,
          "int2":2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JsonLevel2 will be:

```
public class JsonLevel2 {
    String key1;
    String key2;
    String key3;
    Map<String,Object>jsonLevel3;
```

In this way, the value of the map could be everything (is not forced to be a String as before). So, after you will deserialize your json you could do the same thing of before, whatever is the content of JsonLevel3:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String filename="/pathTo/json.json";
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
    JsonLevel jsonlevel= gson.fromJson(reader, JsonLevel.class);
    System.out.println("jsonlevel: " + gson.toJson(jsonlevel));

    Map<String, Object> jl3 = jsonlevel.getJsonLevel1().getJsonLevel2().getJsonLevel3();
    Map<String, Integer> jl4= (Map<String, Integer>) jl3.get("jsonLevel4");

    JsonLevel3 jlev3=gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(jl3), JsonLevel3.class);
    JsonLevel4 jlev4= gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(jl4), JsonLevel4.class);

    System.out.println("jlev3: " + gson.toJson(jlev3));
    System.out.println("jlev4: " + gson.toJson(jlev4));
```

Comment: Thats a very nice way out. But the problem is JsonLevel3 might not be the last level. It may have JsonLevel4 inside it. and in project-d JsonLevel4 structure is different. Actually there are almost 10 projects, with equal json structure upto level 3 and then it is different for different projects. I want to keep the common class structure in common project.

Comment: Just one question. While reading the values from the map by iterating it. How can I distinguish between Primitive and Object.